# Need validation code so only 1 of 3 Boolean fields can be true

Tags: forms, validation, ms-access, boolean, ms-access-2010

Access 2010: I have a table that includes 3 Boolean fields - call them Field_A, Field_B, and Field_C.

On the data entry form, a user should be able to check (make the value TRUE) any one of those options, but only one option can be TRUE at any time.  If Field_B is already true and the user wants to change it so Field_C is the option selected to be TRUE, he should first have to unselect Field_B (reset it to FALSE) before he can check the box on the form for Field_C.

So I need some validation code for each of these fields which, if the user tries to set one field to TRUE, checks the status of the other two fields.  If both other fields are currently FALSE, it allows the current field to be changed to TRUE.  But if either of the other fields is currently TRUE, it should create a popup message saying there's already another selection and the other field must first be changed to FALSE before he can proceed.

I tried this using the numerical values for the Yes/No option, setting a conditional validation that required the sum of the other two values to be zero before allowing the field of interest (e.g. Field_A) to be changed to TRUE (value = -1) (just something like `([Field_B] + [Field_C]) =0`, but I kept getting syntax errors. I'm new enough to this that I don't know if it really is just a simple syntax problem, or if a completely different approach is needed.

Last piece of info-- it's acceptable to have all 3 fields set to FALSE, so I don't want something that forces one of them to become TRUE if another is changed back from TRUE to FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two acceptable combinations for those 3 check boxes:

1. all are `False` (unchecked)
2. only one can be `True` (checked)

So that means the sum of those check box values must be either 0 or -1.

```vb
? False + False + False
 0 
? False + False + True
-1
```

You can add a function in the form's code module ...

```vb
Private Function checkBoxProblem() As Boolean
    Dim blnReturn As Boolean
    Dim intSum As Integer
    Dim strPrompt As String

    intSum = Nz(Me.Field_A, 0) + Nz(Me.Field_B, 0) + Nz(Me.Field_C, 0)
    If Not (intSum = 0 Or intSum = -1) Then
        strPrompt = "only one box can be checked"
        MsgBox strPrompt
        blnReturn = True
    Else
        blnReturn = False
    End If
    checkBoxProblem = blnReturn
End Function
```

Then call the function from the before update events of each of those 3 check boxes.

```vb
Private Sub Field_A_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = checkBoxProblem
End Sub
Private Sub Field_B_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = checkBoxProblem
End Sub
Private Sub Field_C_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = checkBoxProblem
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow!  This was perfect-- does exactly what I wanted.  I'm sorry I couldn't get back to this project and respond for so long, but tonight it only took me a few minutes to see what you were doing, and apply the code to my database.  Thanks for showing me the Nz function.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of code behind your data-entry form should do the trick. Try something along these lines:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Field_A_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Const ThisField = "Field_A"
    If Me.Field_A.Value Then
        If Me.Field_B.Value Then
            ShowMyMessage "Field_B", ThisField
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf Me.Field_C.Value Then
            ShowMyMessage "Field_C", ThisField
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Field_B_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Const ThisField = "Field_B"
    If Me.Field_B.Value Then
        If Me.Field_A.Value Then
            ShowMyMessage "Field_A", ThisField
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf Me.Field_C.Value Then
            ShowMyMessage "Field_C", ThisField
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Field_C_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Const ThisField = "Field_C"
    If Me.Field_C.Value Then
        If Me.Field_B.Value Then
            ShowMyMessage "Field_B", ThisField
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf Me.Field_A.Value Then
            ShowMyMessage "Field_A", ThisField
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowMyMessage(OtherField As String, CurrentField As String)
    MsgBox _
            "You must un-select """ & OtherField & """" & _
                " before you can select """ & CurrentField & """", _
            vbExclamation, _
            "Mutually exclusive options conflict"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I ended up going with HansUp's example since it used my original approach of testing the Boolean integer values.